# I am having trouble connecting my Arduino Uno R3 to my Macbook

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have selected the correct board and port, but am getting the same error each time I try to upload a simple blink program to the board:

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

I have searched all over for a solution to this problem but nothing seems to be working. The 'ON' LED is displaying green and the built-in LED on PIN 13 blinks orange when I turn on and reset the board, which leads me to believe that my board and USB cable are both working properly.

I have had the board for a couple of years and am just playing around with it for the first time in a while. If anyone knows of why this may be happenning, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: So, I've tried my arduino on two other lab computers from my school and I get the same error. I can only assume that my Arduino is broken (or possibly my USB cable?) and there is no hope left for me. Thanks for anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Macbooks need an FTDI driver to connect to Arduino over USB, there is a very helpful guide here that should help: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/mac

You'll install a package, reboot and be ready to go!

Comment: Uno don't use FTDI.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work for me. I'm getting the same errors with avrdude programmer not responding. I am wondering if it's possible for the board to be damaged or broken somehow. The Arduino IDE recognizes my board, since it comes up as /dev/cu.usbmodem1411 (Arduino/Genuino Uno), so I'm not sure that the problem lies in the USB connection but in the board itself.